# How to split line using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I need to create regular expression which will split first line from file like this:

```
Array[0] = 0 
Array[1] = 2
Array[2] = 3
```

Here is a example of this file

```
0 > 2 3
2 > 0 2
0 > 1 1
1 > 2 4
```

I tried doing this and it worked without blank characters like this `0>2 3` but I heard from my teacher that space between `>` is necessary.

My regular expression:

```
String[] wartosci = line.split(">|\\s");
```

How to do that?

Comment: `String[] wartosci = line.split("[>\\s]+");`

Comment: Thanks you very much. It is working perfectly

Comment: anyone willing to grab the above comment and make it as an answer?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I think it can be even improved :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] wartosci = line.split("[>\\s]+");
```

This will split on any sequence of `>` and whitespace characters. See [documentation of Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to split on any non-digit. So, use

```
String results[] = s.split("\\D+");
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/gaXoOT)

Here, `\D+` matches 1 or more non-digit characters.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/gaXoOT):

```
String s = "0 > 2 3";
String results[] = s.split("\\D+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
// => [0, 2, 3]
```

Note that Avinash's `[>\\s]+` is a whitelist approach, and if you plan to follow it, you might need to expand the character class with other symbols (like `<`, `=`, or even `-`...

And a couple of words about performance: your `>|\\s` regex is using one symbol alternation that is much less efficient that a character class `[>\\s]` that invloves much less backtracking (since it is compiled into 1 "entity" in the "regex internal program"). Whenever you wanted to match 1 symbol from a set of characters, use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).